# Permissions in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, security, permissions

We have developed an ERP system in Windows Forms,  users need to have granular permissions throughout the system. To achieve this, each form is pretty much its own exe. We have a main menu where we add a MenuItem to the database and we can then give users permission to access this.  We will then pass a  Guid through to each exe as an id for the "Session". Permissions are checked before the exe is launched not by the exe itself.

So our "Main Menu" is built up of these exe's the table is "Id, Title, Exe,..,..).

So over the years the project has grown, we now have one solution with over 800 small projects in it and  4 shared dll's (Data, BL,UI,Printing).  Our VS solution really struggles with performance.

I was thinking of combining the forms into a few projects, using a custom attribute to use reflection to build the menu. I guess then, instead of launching an exe we would use reflection to instantiate the form and display it? Would this be the best way to go about this? Or is there some framework designed for Windows Forms that can handle this?

Also would this improve VS performance? same amount of code just less projects?

Aside from this we also have in-app permissions used to enable/disable controls. Though i don't think they would be affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your intermediate steps but an approach I've used recently in an erp system was to use a variation of the command pattern. If you put into a command the logic to check security and start the form or a variation of that then you could use reflection to locate the command or locate them all at startup and store them in a list. either way it is relatively simple to do.

```
public interface ICommand
{
    Guid GetUniqueId();
    bool Execute();
}
```

Then the actual command can be something like

```
  public class YourWinformCommand: ICommand
    {
        private User _user;
        private Guid _securityCode = new Guid(".......");

        public Guid GetUniqueId()
        {
            return _securityCode;
        }

        public  bool Execute()
        {

            if (_user.HasAccessTo(_securityCode))
            {
                //Load the winform here.

                return true
            }

             return false;
        }
    }
```

With a command for each entry point you should be able to merge the winforms into logical sets and place them in dlls instead. now once that's done use reflection locate a given command by its interface and testing for the identifier

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains methods to construct a concrete object from an interface.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ServiceFactory
    {


        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a concrete instance of an interface
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The interface of the object</typeparam>
        /// <returns>If found, a concrete object is returned that implements the interface</returns>
        public static T Build<T>() where T : class
        {
            string applicationPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(applicationPath, "*.dll");

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                // Dynamically load the selected assembly.
                Assembly theAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

                // See if the type implements T.
                foreach (Type type in theAssembly.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (ImplementsInterface(type, typeof(T)))
                    {
                        // Use late binding to create the type.
                        return (T) theAssembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static bool ImplementsInterface(this Type type, Type ifaceType)
        {
            return type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == ifaceType);
        }

}
```

From that code modify it to include the guid in the equation or modify it to return all commands, your choice.

Hope it helps.